# solution verification for finding ideal point(point at infinity) of a line

Tags: proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

I have the line l represented in the following way:

$$
l: \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y-2t=0 \\ 
2x+z-3t-0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

My idea is the following:

Since it's an point at infinity then $t=0$. I choose $x=1 \implies y=-1 \implies z=-2$. Therefore a point at infinity should be the point $P(1,-1, -2, 0)$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct. Shouldn't the notation be $(1:-1:-2:0)$?

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the notation, I really don't know. I find that the notation we use in eastern-European countries is far different from the one used in western-European for example.

Comment: It's to make the difference between affine coordinates, and projective coordinates, which are defined up to a non-zero factor. B.t.w., the notation should rather be with brackets  – $[1:-1:-2:0]$. But as you say, it may differ in different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea is correct.

The plane at infinity has equation $t=0$. Then you have the system of equations:

\begin{cases}
x+y=0\\
2x+z=0
\end{cases}

You can rewrite it as

\begin{cases}
y=-x\\
z=-2x
\end{cases}

So every solution has the form $(x,-x,-2x,0)$. Since the system of coordinates we are using is homogeneous, we can choose a non zero value for $x$. By putting $x=1$, for example, we obtain
$
P(1,-1,-2,0).
$